# Redirect loop in Apache

Tags: html, .htaccess, http, ubuntu, apache2

I am trying to forward the location of a directory, e.g., `www.example.com/dir` to a file in itself, e.g., `www.example.com/dir/file.php`. The following is my `.htaccess` configuration:

```
Redirect /dir http://example.com/dir/file.php.
```

I am getting a redirect loop in this fashion:

```
example.com/dir/file.php/file.php/file.php/+...+file.php ad nauseam.
```

Fairly new at this logic so clearly I may have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

The `Redirect` directive is prefix matching, and everything after the match (ie. `/file.php`) is appended onto the end of the target URL, hence the redirect loop.

However, you can use `RedirectMatch` instead, which matches a specific regex, rather than simple prefix matching. For example:

```
RedirectMatch ^/dir$ /dir/file.php
```